# Prestashop module page not working

Tags: prestashop

i've loaded a backup from an old prestashop 1.4.6.2 website on a subdomain. now i'm experiencing some problems with the module page. whenever i want to expand a module category it refers me to a 404 page. i have error reporting on and only have one error :

*Strict Standards: Declaration of jbx_custominvoice::l() should be compatible with ModuleCore::l($string, $specific = false, $id_lang = NULL) in public_html/presta1.4/classes/Module.php(551) : eval()'d code on line 149*

I checked if it was just as easy as adding those variables to the function, but that didnt change anything except make the error go away. Also when i look in the console from chrome i see the error: 
*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function*

I've looked all over google and prestashop forums but couldnt find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be a firewall to block the access issue